# No design view for Eclipse PDT?

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, eclipse-pdt

I'm currently using Dreamweaver CS5 trial for my php works, and decide to move to Eclipse PDT.

I installed it and it seems I couldn't find the "design view" tab?? Is there only code view for PDT?

Btw, do PHP professionals out there use Design view at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I don't think you will find it built in. You can look for a plugin. I found one right away from a Google search. It costs money though. http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-12.html

Check out this question because it's related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868/what-is-the-best-html-editor-for-eclipse

Comment: Thx, I'm now using the Web Page Editor plugin for eclipse with design view, however is there anything like inserting button, table, textfield, radio button etc. directly to the web page design view just like Dreamweaver or Visual Studio?

Comment: Not built-in, but like I said you might be able to find a plugin. Do a search for "eclipse wysiwyg html designer plugin"